# how can I to ensure Facebook app is always running on apps.facebook.com

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have a basic canvas Facebook app with a web template. I tried to ensure that the app always runs under Facebook but eventually failed.

I get signed request when I first log-in to app but after that since I'm running on a web template I can't get any feedback from Facebook.

I tried some javascript code like

```
if (window == top) { goHome(); }
```

to check if the site is under Facebook frame but I couldn't get top Facebook frame location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
if (parent.location.href == self.location.href) {

            window.location.href = "https://url to app";
        }
```